# Use White UI and FlaUI together

Tags: c#, white-framework

Can I use WhiteUI and FlaUI together in a project?

```
public TestStack.White.Application app = null;
public TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowItems.Window=null;
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"winword.exe");
var application = Application.Launch(processStartInfo);
app=Application.Attach("winword");
FlaUI.Core.Application fpp = (FlaUI.Core.Application)app;
TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowItems.Window window = app.GetWindow("Microsoft Word");
FlaUI.Core.AutomationElements.Window fwin = (FlaUI.Core.AutomationElements.Window) Window;
```

Unable to cast window and application of Test Stack to FlaUI.

Comment: I think you need to [edit] this question and share a bit more information. Show us what you have tried and share exactly what results you get. Details like language might help, too. Right now this it is unclear how you are doing whatever you are doing.

Comment: I would like to use some of the method for performing actions on Combo box using FlaUI. Since using White framework for combo selection is not working.

Comment: SO is not a threaded forum, and comments can be deleted. You should [edit] the question and put your details in there.

Comment: Why would you want to use FlaUI and White together? There should be nothing FlaUI cannot do what White can. If that is the case, please create an issue in FlaUI.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get the underlying `AutomationElement` from the White control and then create the FlaUI control using that `AutomationElement`. This means you will be limited to using UIAv2 only since White does not have a UIAv3 implementation.

Every [`UIItem`](https://github.com/TestStack/White/blob/master/src/TestStack.White/UIItems/UIItem.cs) in White exposed a [`AutomationElement`](https://github.com/TestStack/White/blob/master/src/TestStack.White/UIItems/UIItem.cs#L65) property where you can get the underlying UIAv2 wrapper. Then you should be able to construct the FlaUI [`UIA2FrameworkAutomationElement`](https://github.com/Roemer/FlaUI/blob/master/src/FlaUI.UIA2/UIA2FrameworkAutomationElement.cs#L21) using the `AutomationElement` from White as the second parameter. Then you will pass the `UIA2FrameworkAutomationElement`from FlaUI into the [`ComboBox`](https://github.com/Roemer/FlaUI/blob/master/src/FlaUI.Core/AutomationElements/ComboBox.cs) from FlaUI. So it will look something like the following.

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"winword.exe");
var application = Application.Launch(processStartInfo);
TestStack.White.Application app = Application.Attach("winword");
TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowItems.Window window = app.GetWindow("Microsoft Word");
TestStack.White.UIItems.ListBoxItems.ComboBox whiteCombox = window.Get<ComboBox>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("MyComboBox"));
var flaUiAutomationElment = new FlaUI.UIA2.UIA2FrameworkAutomationElement(new UIA2Automation(), whiteCombox.AutomationElement);
var flaUiComboBox = new FlaUI.Core.AutomationElements.ComboBox(flaUiAutomationElment);
```

I would suggest just doing everything in FlaUI if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Max, But, I am trying to use the above mentioned code snippet, I am seeing compilation error "The type or namesapce name 'UIA2FrameworkAutomationElement' deos not exists in the namespace FlaUI.UIA2. Could you help me resolve this

Comment: @user8740533 did you install the nuget package for FlaUI UIA2?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: Yes, because both solutins work on the same page, and that's Automation UI.
But you gonna need to inform to FLAUI what process ID you are dealing with, like below:

```
var automation = new UIA3Automation(); //start new instance of FALUI
var app = FlaUI.Core.Application.Attach(application.Process.Id); //.Id its a property of you var application
var window = app.GetMainWindow(automation); //With that, FlaUI gets hold of the window
```

After you deal with the FLAUI, you can attach the same ID on the White and vice-versa. It's pretty straight foward.